# FIO : How can we do overlapped IO using FIO switches?

Tags: linux, io, storage

Can someone share how do we build a IO workload that performs IO on same partition in overlapped fashion? i.e, Lets say, 1 job doing 4k IO on disk partition /dev/sda start=0k to end=1GB.

So, Using FIO, can we do something like, 1 WL doing 4k write in the first pass, and offset getting incremented by 3k so that last 1k gets overlapped on the next 4k write.

Please let know if this is doable via FIO. Thank you.

Comment: note: the phrase "overlapped I/O" is already in common usage, and not in the way you use it

Comment: @BenVoigt, Thank you for the replies. Do you mind explaining more on this?

Comment: On the rather popular Windows OS, "overlapped I/O" refers to asynchronous operations overlapping in time... but each operation must refer to a distinct region of a file, or else non-deterministic behavior happens.  The big performance advantage from having multiple requests in-flight simultaneously comes from the ability (at multiple layers in the I/O stack) to reorder the requests or complete them out of requested order.